# Allocating memory specified by a reference variable for nested arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I am supposed to implement a function

```
void foo(string** &grid);
```

Where I populate the given reference with a freshly allocated array or array of strings, I'd imagine.

I've done things like

```
void foo(string** &grid) {
        grid = new string[4][4];
}
```

But I get this error:

```
error: cannot convert 'std::string (*)[4] {aka std::basic_string<char> (*)[4]}' to 'std::string** {aka std::basic_string<char>**} in assignment
```

Hm.

I see what this error is trying to tell me, but what is my fundamental misunderstanding here, and how would I go about doing what I want to do?

Thank you

Comment: You can't simply new 2D dynamic array with `new[][]` in C++, there is no such syntax in C++ like in Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new string[4][4]` creates a pointer to `string[4]`, not a pointer to pointer to `string`. The closest you can get is something like this:

```
grid = new string*[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    grid[i] = new string[4];
}
```

But note that the 16 `string`s created in the process might not all be stored contiguously in memory.

Comment: Thank you Brian, all makes sense now :)